# Is there an SQL command that gets the min value of a column and the max value of another column that corresponds to that min

Tags: sql

I have 2 columns with data in them. Below is the filtered minimum value for f_z1.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrFe2.png]

Is there an SQL command that I can use to search for min(fz_1) and max(ry_1)? (starting with look for the min of fz_1 first, then go through the corresponding ry_1 values and search for the max) in that case the right answer would be 20.70.

I tried SELECT min(fz_1), max(ry_1) but that just returns the min and max values of these two parameters, not following the train of thought I explicited above...

Comment: Are you using SQL against a Excel file? How are you using xlwings? Please create a [reprex]. This is very easy using the `MIN` and `MAXIFS` Excel formulas, btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fz_1, rz_1 FROM my_table
ORDER BY fz_1, rz_1 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I expect this will run much faster than any subquery, because `LIMIT 1` should be optimized.

Comment: Assuming Limit is available; this or Top are likely fastest assuming columns are indexed.

Comment: It's going to be immediate if there is an index, but it's also only one table scan even without any indexes at all.

Answer (score 0):

You must use subqueries and select your table twice. Something like:

```
SELECT s1.min_fz_1, 
(SELECT MAX(ry_1) FROM yourtableW WHERE ry_1 = s1.min_fz_1) AS max_ry_1 
FROM (SELECT MIN(fz_1) AS min_fz_1 FROM yourtable) s1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **Window Functions**, and a sub-query.

Assuming a table name of `table`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 
    fz_1, ry_1, 
    MAX(ry_1) OVER(PARTITION BY fz_1) AS max_ry_for_fz
FROM table) AS subq
WHERE fz_1 = (SELECT MIN(fz_1) FROM table);
```

In the sub-query, for each row, the column `max_ry_for_fz` will contain the maximum value of ry_1, for the value of fz_1 on that row.

The `WHERE` clause in the outer query will ensure that the output resultset only contains the values of *fz_1* which is equal to `MIN(fz_1)`.

If you were to run this query on the data you provided, the result would be as follows:

| fz_1 | ry_1 | max_ry_for_fz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 373 | 19.94 | 20.70 |
| 373 | 20.70 | 20.70 |
| 373 | 19.17 | 20.70 |
| 373 | 20.70 | 20.70 |
| 373 | 19.17 | 20.70 |

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. there's not a single command to achieve what you want.  However, if we break the problem down into two steps we can achieve the desired result with A basic SQL statement.  Keeping in mind order of operations within the SQL statement: First we get the max(Ry_1) of each fz_1, then using the having we eliminate the FZ_1's we don't want. The compiler will execute this in teh following order:

- FROM
- WHERE
- SELECT
- GROUP BY
- HAVING

As such we get the Highest RY_1 value, for each FZ_1 and then eliminate all the FZ_1's except the lowest.

- We use max(RY_1) to get the max value for each group of FZ_1.
- Then use the having clause to limit the FZ_1 to the min F_Z1
  of interest .

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/ifYBnXhG)

```
  SELECT fz_1, max(Ry_1)  Max_RY_1
    FROM CTE
GROUP BY fz_1
  HAVING fz_1 = (SELECT min(FZ_1) FROM CTE)
```

Alternatively: we Limit the data first to just the Min FZ_1 using a where clause and subquery.  This may be more performant because it limits the data to just 1 FZ_1 group and then looks for the max RY_1 a combined index on FZ_1, RY_1 I suspect would allow this to execute optimally.

```
  SELECT fz_1, max(Ry_1)  Max_RY_1
    FROM CTE
   WHERE FZ_1 = (SELECT min(FZ_1) FROM CTE)
GROUP BY fz_1
```

Either Resulting in:

```
+------+----------+
| fz_1 | Max_RY_1 |
+------+----------+
|  373 |    20.70 |
+------+----------+
```